# c# Validating input string and replace to TitleCase using Threading

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I want to check what the user is writing in a textbox and take this input string from the textBox which is contained on a winform, this then needs to converted to have every letter of a word Capitalised.

Using this input, I need to firstly  validate if they have left the text box empty, Null. Second step was to check if they have formed a coherent sentence using Title case "in other words, making sure they haven't been typing with caps lock on or vise versa".

I have been researching into Threading and Regex with regards to Validation. Using threading i have used the methods IsLower() and  then the ToLower(). This may be a rather long way of converting the input, at a bare minimum I could just convert all of the first letter of every word to upper case and all the middle to lower.

If i havent explained my issue well enough just ask and will gladly fire over any extra info please find my source code below:

```
        string myText = tbProductId.Text;

        //// Check for null values
        if (myText.Equals(""))
        {    //// display Error prompt
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter somthing");
            //// Get length of entered string
        }

        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < myText.Length; i++)
            {
                //// check if lower case
                if (char.IsLower(myText[i]))
                {
                    string asTitleCase = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.
                    ToTitleCase(myText.ToLower());
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter non Captilised strings");

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < myText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(myText[i]))
                {
                    string asTitleCase = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.
                   ToTitleCase(myText.ToUpper());
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter strings in Title Case");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like you just needed to take the for loop part out of the outer `if` block, into an `else` block. what you are currently doing is looping over an empty string, so execution will never enter the loop. I don't get the "threading" part - what do you mean?

Comment: This looks like an incomplete piece of code. Seems like you want to make sure the string contains both upper and lowercase letters and that it should not be empty. Something like `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myText) &&
    myText.Any(char.IsLower) &&
    myText.Any(char.IsDigit)) { return true; }`

Comment: For example "Apple" will pass your validation? or it must be converted to "APPLE"?

Comment: Thanks for you advice  @dlatikay, this has allowed the loop now to iterate through Actual values and now checks for the null value and also for capitalisation. however now i need to replace the beginning of every letter with a capital . so like the following "HELLO WORLD, I NEED TO CHANGE" to " Hello World, I Need To Change"

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew yes you are right i have replaced the code above with the complete method, which includes both ToUpper() and To Lower()  and thanks for your response will give it a go.

Comment: @S.Petrosov Yes, that is exactly what i want to do the first letter of every word.

Comment: Check the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx. It basically does what you're asking.

Comment: what if you omitted the loops altogether and just compare `if(myText != asTitleCase) { ... }`?

Comment: @dlatikay   I am strugling to implement this without the loopdo you mean just have one if statement? or all of the currrent ones nested within each other ?

Comment: All of the examples i have used have all been for console projects, and this is a winform projects I have been able to do it in console but i just cant apply it to my winform app

Comment: If you could just explain in words what you need we might be able to help more.

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew I wasn't aware my comments were not clear, they seemed it in my head lol. Well I have created a Win Form project of which takes its user input values from a text-box . I need to essentially validate their input and ensure they are not entering the wrong format. The format is Title Case, Capital letter on the beginning of every word. So say if they enter the following "HELLO WORLD" it will then be replaced with " Hello World", And this will change the text box after they have clicked off.

Comment: Aha, so, you want to convert any user input string into title case string? Then it is a solved issue. Just after checking if the text property is not null or empty, use `tbProductId.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(tbProductId.Text);`.

Comment: Nice one @WiktorStribiżew this solution does work however, if i enter the first word correctly and second incorrectly say "Hello world" it will  move the cursor to the begining and start replaing behind the first word, any ideas? I have placed your snippet in an else after the if

Comment: You have it in the _TextChanged event, right? So, after the `.Text` property modification, the cursor will be moved to the beginning, it is expected. What do you expect? Keep the cursor where it was? Then save the position to a variable, and after the TextChanged event put it back.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew This solution  worked after i added a couple more functions to move the cursor back to where it was left. i have just encountered the issue of CapsLock and Shift, of which do not work with this method, any ideas of how to get round this issue? cheers

Comment: Sorry, it is late here, and I do not have access to VS here. If I repro your issue, I will come back with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the feedback and help, please find the solution attached below provided by @ Wiktor Stribiżew. However there is one more issue, when shift is held it is inactive and doesnt work any ideas why it would be working with caps lock on but not with shift ?

```
   string myText = tbProductId.Text;
        if (myText.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter somthing");
        }
        else
        {
            tbProductId.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInf‌​o.ToTitleCase(tbProd‌​uctId.Text);

            tbProductId.Focus();
            tbProductId.Select(tbProductId.Text.Length, 0);
            //Move Cursor to location of where error

        }
```

Comment: all works fine apart from white space and the shift issue